# PROBLEMA CON API DE NEXTJS (Javascript fetch)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, nextjs

necesito ayuda porque cuando hago una petición me salta un error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Aquí dejo los codigos, son algo simples porque estoy aprendiendo NextJs y es solo una prueba pero no consigo de ninguna manera que me de el resultado que necesito.

Contexto del código: Estoy intentando setear cookies, pero NextJs según la documentación no me lo permite desde el lado del servidor sin rutas API. Asique quiero crear una respuesta POST de http que cree esas cookies. Pero no consigo coger los datos del body. Todo me da error.

Códigos:
`app\auth\login\page.jsx`

```js
'use server'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import {useParams, useSearchParams, redirect} from 'next/navigation'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const searchParams = req.searchParams
  
  const code = req.searchParams['code']

  const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_ENDPOINT

  if (code) {
    var body = new URLSearchParams({
      'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
      'scope': 'identify email'
    })
    const r = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/oauth2/token`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: body,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    })
  
    if (!r.ok) {
      var res = await r.json();
      console.error(res)
    } else {
      var res = await r.json();
      console.log(res['access_token'])

      var access_token = res['access_token']

      const user_res = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/users/@me`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        }
    })

      const user = await user_res.json()

      var body_a = {
        "user": user,
      }
      const cookies_res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/discord/cookies`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body_a,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      })

      const cookies_api = await cookies_res.json()

      console.log(cookies_api)
    }
  } else {
    redirect(new URL(`https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${process.env.CLIENT_ID}&scope=identify&state=15773059ghq9183habn&redirect_uri=${process.env.REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`))
  }
}
```

`api\discord\cookies` ESTA COMENTADO PORQUE HASTA QUE NO CONSIGA LOS DATOS DEL BODY NO TENGO LA VARIABLE user

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
export async function POST(request) {
    try {
      const data = await request.json()
      console.log(data);
        
      return new Response({'message': 'success'});
    
    
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return new Response(null, { status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request" });
      }
    // try {
    //     const user = body['user']

    //     cookies().set('discord_avatar', user.avatar)
    //     cookies().set('discord_id', user.id)
    //     cookies().set('discord_username', user.username)
    //     cookies().set('discord_access_token', access_token)
    // } catch(err) {
    //     return Response.json({'err': err})
    // }
}
```

Y AQUÍ EL CODIGO DEL FETCH (LO DI ARRIBA, PERO AQUI LO PONGO AISLADO POR SI NO QUIEREN VER TODO EL CODIGO DE ARRIBA)

```js
      var body_a = {
        "user": user,
      }
      const cookies_res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/discord/cookies`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body_a,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      })
```

Comment: ¿Hiciste un `console.log` de la respuesta que estás obteniendo del servidor?